# Registry keys for automatic time and time zones

Tags: command-line, windows-10, windows-registry

Windows 10.

I would like to know the registry keys responsible for **"Set time automatically"** and **"Set time zone automatically"** in **Settings > Time and Language** so I can modify them using the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters](time)
"Type"="NoSync" (off)
"Type"="NTP"    (on)


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tzautoupdate](time zone)
"Start"=dword:00000003 (on)
"Start"=dword:00000004 (off)
```

Comment: I also found how how to do this using a tool called Process Monitor. I followed instructions at this web page: http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/all/

Comment: The values for the "Start" DWord are backwards.  3="Automatically Set Time Zone" and 4="Manually Set Time Zone" (at least as of Windows 10 v1703; just confirmed on several PCs)

Answer (score -1):

This is the 'oficial' webpage (on MicroSoft web server) where it is explained, just in case anyone has any kind of misgiving:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/cannot-set-timezone-automatically

Hope this can help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.